# Can I make Steam give me a description or screenshots of a game when browsing my library?

Tags: steam

When I click a game in my library that I've never played, the right side of the window presents a lot of info I don't want and virtually none of the info that I do. Is there some way to change this behavior?

Comment: I know what you mean! After buying a few bundles, my library is full of games that I don't know. They could really use at least *one* graphic and *one* sentence to give me any idea what they're like.

Answer (score 4):

The Library page for a game is generally geared towards people who already own that game, which is why it contains things like news, achievements, etc. And unfortunately, no, it's not customizable.

There is, however, a page in Steam for every game that gives a description, shows Screenshot, etc. The game's Store Page. And the library page should generally always contain a 'Store Page' link. It's not quite what you wanted, but it's AFAIK as close to what you asked for as Steam has.

Comment: I do already own the game. The store page is actually pretty much exactly what I want; I just need to figure out how to make it the default page.

Comment: @Sparr part of what I'm saying is that you really can't. Steam's interface isn't exactly the most customizable thing in the world.

Comment: Oh, never underestimate what frustration can accomplish. I might do this with a web proxy that replaces game pages with store pages :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, you have 2 solutions

- First display only installed games. See screenshot below (In red on the left)
- Second : Change the layout of the Library. See screenshot below (In red on the right)

[image]

Comment: This is half a solution: it does give some larger promo graphics. No descriptions or blurbs though.

Comment: the promo graphics seem to mostly just be a logo, but this is a tiny step in the right direction, thanks.